# memcpy.asm not found error

Tags: c++, optix

I am working in Optix Using Visual studio 2013 platform, I have been working over month , suddenly I got this error, "memcpy.asm not found".

I found this file in Visual studio folder but it says "The source file is different from when the module was built"

Comment: I assume this is while debugging.

Comment: Thank you for reply, I got my mistake! when you declare a variable in a structure and initialize the value from different class without proper assignment of pointer you will get this error.

Answer (score 3):

Look carefully at the error, often this comes up as a secondary message because the debugger is trying to load "memcpy.asm" in order to show you debugging information because a memcpy failed, not because your program is actually missing "memcpy.asm"

[Heres someone with a similar issue](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/860366/optix/memcpy-asm-not-found-error-/), in short - check the stack trace to see where the issue originated in your code, probably with trying to copy memory to an uninitialized pointer or something.