# guard_dispatch.asm not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-debugging

I have activated the Control Flow Guard option (/guard:cf) to compile C++ programs in debug mode with Visual Studio 2017.

When I step inside a function with the debugger, Visual Studio shows the following page:

[image: Not Found]

This is quite anoying. I would like to get rid of this page. Do you know where I can find or download the source of `guard_dispatch.asm`?

In the following VC path, I see some assembly files like `memcpy.asm` but there is no `guard_dispatch.asm`:
`C:\dev\vs150\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\crt\src\i386`

---

If I look the callstack, the debugger stops in `_guard_dispatch_icall_nop ()`:

[image: callstack]

I've tried to define natstepfilter rule to don't step into this function but it doesn't help:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <StepFilter xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/natstepfilter/2010">
    <Function><Name>_guard_dispatch_icall_nop</Name><Action>NoStepInto</Action></Function>
    </StepFilter>
```

---

I've tried also to uncheck the checkbox at `DEBUG / Options / Debugging / General / Enable address-level debugging / Show disassembly if source is not available` but it doesn't help.

---

Any ideas how to get ride of this page?

Comment: Will the problem occur in VS2022? This is probably due to code error . [memcpy.asm not found error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31701195/memcpy-asm-not-found-error).  Can  you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Thanks @MinxinYu-MSFT for your interest. I haven't found a way to build a minimal reproducible example. My case is about an indirect call with loading a library dynamically with LoadLibrary (), getting an interface pointer and calling a virtual function. I was not able to have this guard_dispatch.asm page... However, by trying to build this minimal example, I have found a solution to my issue. I'm posting my result as an answer.

Comment: Glad to know your problem has been solved!  You could accept it as an answer to close the thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting various things during a day, I have found one solution to this issue. The page `guard_dispatch.asm not found` doesn't appear if the code is compiled with the option `/JMC` (Just My Code). From UI, this option can be set through: `Configuration Properties / C/C++ / General / Support Just My Code Debugging`.